# A dynamic array that changes size on one click function and being used on in another click function

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I'm programming something for a school task and having a problem. I need to create an array, then I need to change its size on one-click function(the size of the array depends on the button you click, there are 3 options, each one makes a different size array) and then use it in another click functioned.

I don't know how to do it (I can't make it static because it's size needs to be changed in a click function) I thought about just creating the array in the function instead of changing its size but I can't because then I can not use it in the other function. I wanted to ask if I am able to change an outside array size in a function or create an array in a function and then use it in another one, and if I am, how?

Please help, thanks in advance

C#

Comment: in c#, the idiomatic way to do what you are looking for is using a List<something>.
It can be a class member variable. And by the way, there is no problem also declaring it as static, which I would avoid anyway in your case

Answer (score 0):

Array not suitable for the actions you specified in the question.
Array don't have `Add` and `Remove` functional.
You can use List instead Arrays.
List is dynamic data structure and very easy to use.

[List usage](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-list)

[Microsoft docs: List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).